# Logic Analyzer with ground probe missing

Tags: logic-analyzer

I'm playing around with a USB logic analyzer ([DSLogic Plus](https://www.dreamsourcelab.com/product/)) to look at some RS232 signals. Everything seems to be working fine, but I just noticed that the probe to ground wasn't connected properly. So only the RX and TX lines were connected to the logic analyzer.

How was I getting any kind of good data without the ground being connected?

Just to set the expectation level: I'm a software guy who knows something about programming low-level devices, but my electronics knowledge is extremely basic.

A description of the connections between the devices:

The devices communicating over the RS232 link are an iMX6-based board and a device that is based on a Nordic nRF chip.  The RS232 link is not TTL level, it's level shifted to RS232 levels:

```
     +-------+                        +--------+
     | iMX6  | <====== rs232 ========>| Nordic |
     +-------+           ^            +--------+
                         |
                         |
                    +---------+
                    | DS Logic|
                    +---------+
                         |
                        usb
                         |
                    +---------+
                    | PC      |
                    +---------+
```

The devices are powered by:

- iMX6:   a 12V DC brick
- Nordic: a bench power supply at 9V
- PC:     household main
- DS Logic: a powered hub connected to the PC

Comment: Were those signals going to or from the same PC to which the USB based analyzer was connected?  If so you already had a common ground, just not one very good at high frequency.  Traditional desktops may also have ground through to the mains, and by extension other mains powered equipment.  But many laptop supplies do not...

Comment: Please explain how the system was connected? For example, if the PC ground already has connection to the measured device ground, for example via USB or mains connection, then there already is a ground connection between them.

Comment: I've updated the question with a diagram for how the devices involved are connected and powered.  It did occur to me that the low frequency of the of the RS232 (115200bps) might be a factor, but I still wanted to understand what's going on better.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Actually that does not explain the details enough to be answered. Is the PC connected to earthed mains socket with earthed mains cable? Is the bench power supply connected to mains socket with earthed mains cable, and does it have isolated or earth referenced output? Is the i.MX6 power brick also having an earthed mains plug connected with earthed mains cable, and does it have floating or earth referenced output? Basically, do the boards with RS232 link have any route to earth ground via any connection? If you are unsure, post photos, device names, links to manuals, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [DS logic input](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZ5wKYnCNcs&t=2s) is simply a 7kΩ resistor in series before the FPGA input (there is also a few zeners for input protection). I'm willing to bet that the xilinx FPGA's input is in the uA or greater for input impedance so it would be like having a 1MegΩ resistor as a load on the RS232, regardless not much current is flowing.

The logic analyzer then triggers a 1 or 0 whenever the voltage reaches a threshold of it's Vil or Vih specs*. The Vil and Vih are triggered when referenced to the ground of the FPGA, which is in turn referenced from the ground of the PC. The ground of the PC is connected to AC mains ground.

Ideally the DS probe would also have a grounding clip as most logic analyzers do to avoid having the thing they are measuring and the logic analyzers ground at different potentials, but if that wasn't connected, then the ground would have gone through the 9V supply or the nordic. (the nordic probably isn't connected to AC mains ground because it is most likely isolated and or double insulated as most brick/wall supplies are, the bench supply is probably not isolated unless it is advertised as such, so I'm willing to bet that your ground is going through the bench supply, you can find out by ohming from the ground to the negative terminal of either supply)

[image]

The grounding system isn't the greatest because there are loops and could be susceptible to AC mains ground noise. This would only be a problem if the ground noise got into ~50mV range which is where Vih would start to trigger on the FPGA.

Comment: with the DSLogic you can set / change the trigger level. works perfectly with mine... it's really one of the better cheap devices

Comment: I thought that with an GPIO FPGA input that couldn't be done

Comment: the 7k Resistor is from the Input to gnd (pulldown do get 0V input if not connected). also with the probes attached the device can handle 30V - 25V more than without, so the coaxial cable must have another 42k build in.

Comment: They must be using ADC's then...

Comment: the pins of most FPGA's can be ajdusted to support different logic standards - in fact I wasn't  aware that it can be done once the device was booted (thought it is hard coded in the initial programming bitstream) - maybe it can be done at runtime or it's partial reconfig or they just reboot the fpga via usb with an patched bitstream.

Comment: No, no ADC's, no ADC would be able to do that speeds without being big and consume a lot of power... the inputs are comparators with a DAC as reference - a 1 bit ADC if you want

Comment: @schnedan Yeah, but that doesn't give you a movable logic level, that only gets you maybe 3 to 5 choices.

Comment: depends on the device... my company designed some asic inputs that way and we use just some standard dacs from a tsmc lib... don't let me lie, but if I remenber they are 8bits or more. and the xilinx fpga's are done at tsmc too, so maybe they haven't designed their own 3bit DAC but just use a one provided by the lib... there is one more advantage: with a higher resolution dac availible you can easily calibrate the chip in the production...

Comment: DS logic also makes an oscilloscope with a simmilar design that uses ADC's

Comment: just connected my device, threshold voltage can be adjusted from 0-5V in 0.1V steps

Comment: Adjustable logic level threshold is easy to achieve with say PWM output and filter cap if needed, to bias the input pin weakly. One logic analyzer just reprogrammed the FPGA so only few bits were different so it just had two levels and most likely configured the FPGA with different IO pin setup.

Comment: Just looked up some Xilinx docu: "All 7 series FPGAs have configurable SelectIO drivers and receivers, supporting a wide variety of standard interfaces. The robust feature set includes programmable control of output strength and slew rate, on-chip termination using digitally-controlled impedance (DCI), and the ability to internally generate a reference voltage (INTERNAL_VREF)." from https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug471_7Series_SelectIO.pdf... so you can select different pullups/pulldowns and ajust the reference voltage per bank. this allows for  a wide of thresholds

Comment: VREFSingle-ended I/O standards with a differential input buffer require an input reference voltage (VREF). When VREF is required within an I/O bank, the two multi-function VREFpins for the bank must be used as VREF supply inputs. 7 series FPGAs can optionally use an internally generated reference voltage by enabling the INTERNAL_VREF constraint. For more information on this constraint, see 7 Series FPGA SelectIO Attributes/Constraints,

Comment: Ah, so thats how they do it thats a cool feature, I've worked with mostly altera FPGA's

Comment: as the Series 7 inernal Vref is limited to •0.60 •0.675 •0.75 •0.90V, I guess the DSLogic has an external DAC for providing Vref to the Input bank

Comment: we used Series 7 recently to simulate our ASIC.... but the downside is: these beasts are very complex... hard to get everything right if you never worked with them before... and at some points the documentation is... not so good

Answer (score 0):

guess you have a connection from the safety pins of your electric plugs [wall socket]... which is normaly almost equal to the neutral conductor of your electric plugs - so even better connected.

I also guess you have luck and good designed power supplys in all devices so GND of your DC voltages is not floating to much.

Also the DS Logic is tolerant to some little DC offsets. But to ensure not to damage the equipment by chance: add the gnd connection!